# getting PHP warning while running application

Tags: php

I am getting a warning in php while running my application

HTML code:

```
      <a href="cart.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span> <?php if($a==true) { ?><?php echo $d->n;  ?> <?php } ?></span></a>
```

PHP code:

```
      $q=$mysqli->query("select object from object_store where Email='$email' ");
      $r=$q->fetch_assoc();
      $d=unserialize($r['object']);
      if(!is_null($d))
      {
      $a=true;
      }
      else
      {
      $a=false;
      }
```

The warning is cant call a member function on non object. I know that at first the value of $d is NULL but having used $a variable for check still the code block of $d  is getting executed. Please suggest a way to remove this warning.

Comment: Most likely the warning references a specific error number? I would guess that command: `$q->fetch_assoc();` since it is the only line in your code that actually uses any object. Actually this is a pretty typical error that has been answered endless times before: you do not do any error checking or handling at all. you blindly trust that your query well succeed. Most likely it does _not_ succeed, but the call returns a boolean false. You cannot call a method on a boolean value.

Comment: my default object value is null and the query is running correctly

Comment: What is a "default object value"? And what line is referenced in the error you get?

Comment: in the HTML code which encloses $a boolean value  it is displaying the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code:

```
$d=unserialize($r['object']);
if(!is_null($d))
```

will always be `true`, since `unserialize` doesn't return `null`.

Try: `if($d != false)` or `if(is_array($d))`